# How to inject an external javascript file into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can an external javascript file be injected into a div. When I try to set it using below code, the div 'toupdate' is not updated with new javascript file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#toupdate').html('<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/5968383.js"></script>');
});

</script>

    <body>
    <div id="toupdate">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6343621.js"></script>
    </div>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your replacement code is being executed before the div 'toupdate' has loaded, you either need to move the `<script>` tag to after the div or put you replacement code within a `$(document).ready()` function like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#toupdate').html('<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/5968383.js"></script>');
});
```

EDIT:

tested and working example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toupdate').children('script').attr('src', 'http://static.polldaddy.com/p/5968383.js');
});​
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m7q3H/45/

Comment: it seems to be loading the new javascript but not updating the UI.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the $.getScript("URL") function
[definition](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Comment: can that function be used to inject the script into a div ?

Comment: Im not entirely sure if it can be, there is a callback function with it that will run after the script has successfully been downloaded, but it seems the script will already have been run at this point. sorry i cant be of more help.